# Why does Annie use a revolver as her primary sidearm when everyone else seems to use semi-automatics?

Tags: character, covert-affairs

In the TV show *[Covert Affairs](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1495708/)* the lead character Annie uses a [Chiappa Rhino revolver](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Covert_Affairs_-_Season_3#Chiappa_Rhino_20DS) as her personal/primary sidearm. This seems to be a distinct stylistic choice for Annie because everyone else seems to prefer semi-automatics. Furthermore the Rhino has a very distinctive design which is different than most revolvers.

Why did they choose to give Annie that pistol, and what is that supposed to say about her? I don't think most of the [main marketing points](http://www.chiappafirearms.com/product/726) for the Rhino's design are a particularly relevant given that:

- Annie is seen as proficient with semi-automatic pistols multiple times in the series while under duress
- Semi-automatics offer a flatter profile and are easier to conceal.